# Textract fails on pdftoppm error

Tags: python, ocr, text-extraction

Running textract under python3 in OSX, a simple test programme fails with:

textract.exceptions.ShellError: The command `pdftoppm page000.pdf /var/folders/hl/vxz79b3d7qd_ktk3dxs6gt680000gn/T/tmp2k0erixi/conv` failed because the executable
`pdftoppm` is not installed on your system.

But the installation of textract indicates that all the required dependencies are in place.

Must be something silly ..... help please!

Comment: Have you tried running pip3 install pdftoppm in terminal?

Comment: Yes - no good. pdftoppm is in the system in /usr/local/Cellar/poppler/0.60.1/bin

Comment: refer http://textract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html